# Justification for 'opinion based' closure on translation question?

Tags: discussion

This is really not a complaint, I am just trying to understand. Could someone explain to me why [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/571185/which-pronoun-is-used-for-spirit-or-ghost-and-is-there-a-rule-that-says-we-must) is considered opinion-based? The OP is actually asking for an explanation of tendencies of English translations of the Bible, not for opinions on the choice of pronouns to replace "the Holy Spirit" in a sentence.

Am I wrong to think that the fact that "spirit" has more than one interpretation (and thus can be replaced with different pronouns accordingly) was mistaken for an opinion-based issue? Or am I missing something here? I can see that the notion of "opinion-based" is still blurry in my mind.

Comment: Your well documented post doesn’t  come up with a definite, unarguable answer. From which, probably, the POB issue.

Comment: So the question is considered opinion-based because of an answer? That seems a bit odd though. Also, the fact that there is not a consistent position in the history of these translations, does it not say something about the English language too? Is it just "opinions"?

Comment: *“the fact that there is not a consistent position in the history of these translations”* leaves room for POB issues. That doesn’t necessarily mean than you shouldn’t have posted your well-researched answer (rewarded with upvotes) but the issues still remains.

Comment: My CV was on 'wrongly sited' rather than POB grounds. I've a large book devoted to 'body, soul, spirit' analyses, including of course the polysemy of the last two terms (add 'heart') and translation from the Hebrew and Greek. The concepts involved underpin the terminology, and I believe that this is better addressed on Christianity.SE. They will address different conceptualisations before / alongside the language attempting to describe reality.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I agree it could do better on another site. But the question was closed as opinion-based, so I was puzzled.

Comment: I voted to reopen because, while the question is theologically motivated (which can only be opinion based with respect to language), it is about how language should deal with it. Specify the opinion, but then ask the objective language question.

Comment: The question has been reopened.

Comment: Yes, I know. I think it is a good question, good food for thought and inspires research. I am grateful.